# Using MS Word, how can highlight a text including border spaces as on StackOverflow?

Tags: microsoft-word, highlighting

Currently, I write a little documentation using `MS Word` and I try to highlight some text as `MS Word` in this sentence.

On StackOverflow, using grave-accent (`) to delimit a word hightlights **one space before**, word between delimiter and **one space after**.

I will do same thing on `MS Word` but I try and I try and I can only highlight the text.

I have tried to add space before and after the word but only the word without spaces is highlighted.

I have tried to use hardspace ... with same result.

Question: In MS Word, how can highlight a text including border spaces ?

PS: this question has been first posted on Stackoverflow where a moderator has decided that it is off-topic. So, I have migrated question and all answers (with user permission) to SuperUser.

Comment: Try creating something like " MS Word "   then highlight everything including double quotes on either sides and carefully delete only the double quotes. See this link how it looks in my Word 2019. https://i.ibb.co/GTzH4d4/msword.png The word 'highlight' in the sentence is highlighted tight and then see the word 'MS Word' the highlight protrudes on either sides.

Comment: @yokki: I have sent a message to first user that has answered to my question so that he can make a Paste/Copy of his answer from StackOverflow to Superuser.

Comment: @patkim: your comment is a good answer (for me). Why have you written a comment and not an answer ?

Comment: A small catch I later found which I was about to update as a next comment is that in this method if it's the last word of the sentence and after period there's nothing, or you start a new paragraph on next line, then this method does not seem to work faithfully. So it does not seem to be a fully working solution.

Comment: Update - In case of last word of the sentence you can introduce a hard space using CTRL + SHIFT + SPACEBAR on right side and then this seems to be working. Try it out and then let me know if I can I post it as an answer. Well and good in case you have already found a solution on SO.

Answer (score 0):

You can apply a Background Shading, which is not obvious because I don't think you will see anything in the User Interface that does that for you unless you have certain languages enabled (e.g. Chinese).

For example, in VBA, to apply shading to *the Selection* (not just a word, but the spaces around it)

```
Sub abitgrey()

With Selection
    .InsertAfter (" ") 
    .MoveLeft Extend:=wdExtend 
    .InsertBefore (" ")
    .MoveRight Extend:=wdExtend
End With 

With Selection.Shading
  .Texture = wdTextureNone
  .BackgroundPatternColor = wdColorGray10
End With

End Sub
```

This is non-trivial because there are side effects when you apply background shading (e.g. other text may be affected). Perhaps worth exploring in a further question.

Answer (score 0):

Space and hardspace characters are the only ASCII characters representing a space, but there exists other characters in UNICODE table

Below is a list of different whitespace unicode characters.

[image]

If I replace left and right space characters by any character greater than U+0020, then `spaces` characters are correclty highlighted.

My error was to have only tried with ASCII `no-break space` character !

For information, I type `&#8192` unicode character in typing `Alt 8 1 9 2` on keyboard.

Answer (score 0):

I have also found another solution a little more tricky.

I type my word between `(` and `)` characters.

Then I highlight `(` + `word` + `)` with a color A.

Then I change font color of `(` and `)` characters to color A.

On screen `(` and `)` characters are invisible because their font color and background color are identical, but the space they occupy are there !

If you want larger spaces around word, you can type multiples `(` characters as this

`(((` + `word` + `)))`